# MySQL-запрос, сформированный при помощи mysqli, не отрабатывает кириллицу

Tags: php, mysqli, кириллица

Добрый день. Я к вам опять со своей кириллицей. Есть два варианта кода:

```
$utfquery = "SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; SET CHARACTER SET utf8";
$utf8 = mysqli_query($link, $utfquery);
```

и номер два:

```
$utfquery = "SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; SET CHARACTER SET utf8";
$utf8 = mysql_query($utfquery);
```

Первый случай "не взлетает". В отличие от старого доброго второго (( Запись `24 июня`, вставляемая скриптом, в первом случае выглядит так: `24 Ð¸ÑŽÐ½Ñ`

Кодировка базы и таблицы - utf8. Кодировка скрипта - тоже utf8, установлена через `mb_internal_encoding("utf-8")`. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Оба способа не надо использовать](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php) - библиотека доступа к `mysql` должна знать используемую кодировку для корректной передачи и экранирования данных. Используйте предназначенный для установки кодировки вызов:

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

Для `PDO` - это параметр `charset` в `DSN`:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world;charset=utf8", 'my_user', 'my_pass');
```

К слову,

> Кодировка скрипта - тоже utf8, установлена через mb_internal_encoding("utf-8")

`mb_internal_encoding` не имеет отношения к кодировке скрипта. Определяет кодировку по-умолчанию в последнем параметре функций `mb_*`.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в процедурном виде это должно выглядеть как `mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');`?

Comment: Да, похоже на то.